# Finding elements in list with highest weightage compared to other elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of values that add up to 100 (percentage). I need to find the values that constitute the highest percentages as compared to others. How do I decide the criteria for filtering the data? Help me with the logic.

Below are a few samples and expected output:

```
input1 = [46.34, 42.42, 5.11, 2.16, 1.23, 1.19, 0.48, 0.4, 0.22, 0.22, 0.09, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04] 
output1 = [46.34, 42.42]

input2 = [32.98, 31.82, 9.76, 3.21, 1.18, 0.43, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11] 
output2 = [32.98, 31.82]

input3 = [37.72, 30.66, 30.66, 0.72, 0.24] 
output3 = [37.72, 30.66, 30.66]
```

The list is already sorted. This is not a 'top n-elements' problem. I cannot just select (eg: top 2 or top 3) elements from the list.

*P.S: I am doing this in `pandas` (groupby) so a logic in pandas is preferable*. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If they're already sorted from highest to lowest, why not just input1[0] and input[1] ?

Comment: consider another example. [95, 5]. In this case, 95 has more weightage so I cant consider 5. I need to decide on a breakpoint for higher values.

Comment: The first thing to do is you could for sure add the first item from input1 to output1, then compare those values based on criteria. Just consider how to approach the problem, maybe by a loop, checking if it's close to 100(%), but also that the values aren't drastically different - again depends on your criteria. Is [80,15,5] expected output just [80] or [80,15] ?

Comment: [80] is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `outlier detection` logic to your use case.
you can calculate the `IQR` of the input list and apply the formula:
`outlier= input1 < q1-1.5*IQR | input1 >q3+1.5*IQR`

The code for the same:

```
q1=pd.Series(input1).quantile(0.25)
q3=pd.Series(input1).quantile(0.75)

IQR=q3-q1
output=list(pd.Series(input1)[(input1< (q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(input1 > (q3 + 1.5 * IQR))])
output
[46.34, 42.42, 5.11]
```

You can change the quantiles to your liking and check for the best possible outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for called  [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile). AFAIK the most common are 50% (aka median) and 90%. One can use [numpy.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to compute a percentile:

```
import numpy as np
def filterByPercentile(data, percentile):
    percentile = np.percentile(data,percentile)
    return data[data >= percentile]

input1 = np.array([46.34, 42.42, 5.11, 2.16, 1.23, 1.19, 0.48, 0.4, 0.22, 0.22, 0.09, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04])
input2 = np.array([32.98, 31.82, 9.76, 3.21, 1.18, 0.43, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11])
input3 = np.array([37.72, 30.66, 30.66, 0.72, 0.24])

print("median:")
print(filterByPercentile(input1,50))
print(filterByPercentile(input2,50))
print(filterByPercentile(input3,50))

print("90%:")
print(filterByPercentile(input1,90))
print(filterByPercentile(input2,90))
print(filterByPercentile(input3,90))
```

output:

```
median:
[46.34 42.42  5.11  2.16  1.23  1.19  0.48]
[32.98 31.82  9.76  3.21  1.18  0.43]
[37.72 30.66 30.66]
90%:
[46.34 42.42]
[32.98 31.82]
[37.72]
```

It's up to you to choose the value for percentile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a crude way for now. You can simplify the process but I can hint you a mechanic. For excample:

```
input3 = [37.72, 30.66, 30.66, 0.72, 0.24] 
output3 = []
output3.append(input3[0])
input3.pop(0)
for i in input3:
    if output3[0] / i <2:
        output3.append(i)
    else:
        continue

print(output3)
[37.72, 30.66, 30.66]
```

Works for other 2 examples as well. Depends on your criteria. Again, this is just crude way to show you and work upon.

Update:
I was thinking about this problem some more. Would need to test more for larger lists or certain values, but you can do it also by list comprehensions by adjusting your criteria (in my example i[0] / i <2)

```
input1 = [46.34, 42.42, 5.11, 2.16, 1.23, 1.19, 0.48, 0.4, 0.22, 0.22, 0.09, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04]
input2 = [32.98, 31.82, 9.76, 3.21, 1.18, 0.43, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11]
input3 = [37.72, 30.66, 30.66, 0.72, 0.24]

output1 = [x if x != input1[0] else x for x in input1 if input1[0] / x <2]
output2 = [x if x != input2[0] else x for x in input2 if input2[0] / x <2]
output3 = [x if x != input3[0] else x for x in input3 if input3[0] / x <2]

result:
[46.34, 42.42]
[32.98, 31.82]
[37.72, 30.66, 30.66]
```